# How to access symfony project from network

Tags: symfony, xampp

I've installed symfony with xampp. I can access it locally, but when I am trying to connect to it from another computer on the same network I am getting 404. 
I can access xampp apache, can access mysql. How to configure symfony?

Comment: Are you trying to access to dev or prod env? If you are in dev you may configure app_dev.php inside web.

Comment: when I am trying to access http://localhost:8000 on the server I see symfony welcome homepage. I can not access it from another computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you didn't configure Symfony using PHP-FastCGI responder or specified listening adapter. *localhost:8000* is a default location upon Symfony's built-in server execution.

There are two choices:

- Run `php app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000` and it'll be accessible from other computers from network,
- (preferred, on production) setup a separate VHost: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?p=57475. **Remember**: setting up a host in *hosts* file is mandatory due the fact the HTTP server distinguishes particular host by domain name.